# Scala Play WS JSON not completely returning

Tags: scala, playframework, ws

In my play application I am calling an endpoint asyncronously using WS. The response is an array of Json. They are extremely long responses and using the standard `Request.get(response => process(response))` the response is coming only partially full leaving me with half a json and unserializable. Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value
[error]  at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 3014277]
[error] com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value
[error]  at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 3014277]
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(ParserMinimalBase.java:682)
```

I have also tried to use

```
request
  .stream()
  .map(response => process(response.bodyAsSource))
```

But I get an error saying:

```
WARN  p.a.l.w.a.StandaloneAhcWSClient$: blockingToByteString is a blocking and unsafe operation!
```

Can someone let me know how I can get the complete json? I would like to make it a JsonArray.

This is my code currently just to check the reponse:

```
request.stream()
  .map { response => {
     println("returned")
     val body = response.bodyAsBytes
     if (response.status == 200 && body.last != ']') {
       println(s"\n$body")
       throw new Exception("Unfinished Json")
       system.terminate()
    }
```

This is my full code:

```
    Await
      .result(
        Future.sequence(Await.result(providers, 30 seconds).map { x: Seq[Provider] =>
          val npis = x.map(provider => ("npi", provider.npi.get))
          val request = AhcWSClient()
            .url("url")
            .addHttpHeaders("Accept" -> "application/json")
            .withQueryStringParameters(npis: _*)
            .withRequestTimeout(15 minutes)
          println(request)

          Thread.sleep(55)
          request
            .stream()
            .map { response =>
              {
                println("returned")
                val body = response.bodyAsBytes
                if (response.status == 200 && body.last != ']') {
                  println(s"\n$body")
                  throw new Exception("Unfinished Json")
                  system.terminate()
                }
              }
            }
        }),
        10 minutes
      )
```

Comment: Actually it's not an error in the second case, it's a warning. Does it work?

Comment: In the second case an error follows saying: 
```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Future timed out after [50 milliseconds]
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait0(Promise.scala:248)
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:261)
 at scala.concurrent.Await$.$anonfun$result$1(package.scala:201)
 at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$DefaultThreadFactory$$anon$1$$anon$2.block(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:59)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3118)
```

Comment: What does your process method looks like? Whatdoes your whole method look like? Seems you are blocking/waiting somewhere.

Comment: FWIW I've seen Play WS Client deal with hundreds of MB and dozens minutes streams without issues. It's definitely something in your code.

Comment: The last block is currently what I have in my code. Above that is me just setting up my request and getting a list of names.

Comment: Just posted the rest of the code!

Comment: Only use `Await` as the last step of your code (in the `main` method typically). Elsewhere just combine `Future`s. Here I think your main issue is the `Thread.sleep` though: why did you put it? Also each request has a 15 minutes timeout but the whole computation is waited "only" for 10mns.

Comment: Also it's not clear what you want to do with response after but loading it all in memory of it's huge (+ many in parallel) will cause you trouble. You might want to use `bodyAsSource` and work with Akka Streams.

Comment: There are over 100 fields in the Json Response, I would like to pick out three of them.